# How to change multiple labels in multiple classes with a tkinter dropdown menu

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, python-class, tkinter-menu

So, I want the user to be able to use my program in English. They should be able to switch to their language via a dropdown-menu. My program has only four pages and a few labels on each, translating them with a toolkit would be unnecessary.

This is, what I got this so far:

```
    # Language Settings
    def display_selected(choice):
        choice = variable.get()
        if choice == "Deutsch":
            languagelabel.config(text=str('Sprache:'))
            Page1(self).label_search.config(text=str('Suche'))

        else:
            languagelabel.config(text=str('Language:'))
            Page1(self).label_search.config(text=str('search'))


    # Dropdown Menu for Languages
    languages = ['Deutsch', 'English']
    variable = StringVar()
    variable.set(languages[0])
    dropdown = OptionMenu(self, variable, *languages, command=display_selected)
```

The languagelabel in the same class changes, but the search_label in the class 'Page1' doesn't. Nothing happens, am I missing something?

I'm a bit of a novice, so any guidance and/or other solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I can think of would be using `StringVar()`s to store the labels that need translation for each language option, and the assigning those variables to each label's `textvariable` parameter

```
# EXAMPLE
lang_label_var = tk.StringVar()
label_search = tk.Label(
    textvariable = lang_label_var
    # whatever other attributes
)
search_label_var = tk.StringVar()
languagelabel = tk.Label(
    textvariable = search_label_var
    # whatever other attributes
)
```

You should be able to `set()` these variables to whichever word is appropriate for English or German with similar logic following `choice = variable.get()`. The label text for each item should update automatically when the variable assigned to `textvariable` is set.

```
if choice == 'Deutsch':
    lang_label_var.set('Sprache:')
    search_label_var.set('Suche')
elif choice == 'English':
    lang_label_var.set('Language:')
    search_label_var.set('Search')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I got this problem: 
`AttributeError: 'Page1' object has no attribute 'search_label_var`
I tried: `Page1(self).search_label_var.set('Search')`
How can I change the label across classes?

Comment: The easiest way I've found to share Tk variable data is to declare (and set) the `StringVar()` in your root class, then pass a reference to your root class to any child widget classes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646605/how-to-access-variables-from-different-classes-in-tkinter)). Then access the variable from "Page1" via `self.controller.shared_data['search_label_var'].get()` (using the names from the method shown in the linked answer). The root class reference is called `controller` in that answer, but naturally you can call it whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found it too. But you helped me a loot!!!!

Comment: This is a similar solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533079/how-to-properly-access-a-stringvar-of-a-class-from-another-class-python-tk) without you I wouldn't have found It. Thank you!